# Using ApplicationCommands in WPF PRISM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

After studying several [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048501/how-to-bind-application-commands-to-view-modelwpf)[&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393497/wpf-binding-application-commands-to-viewmodel-icommand)[A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823872/1865613) o[n](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0604f1c9-cc2b-48d8-ba70-5e2ab7b8526f/applicationcommands-class-and-mvvm?forum=wpf) s[tackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328434/wpf-handle-an-applicationcommand-in-the-viewmodel), s[ome](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/commands/using-commands/) t[utorials](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Built-in-Application-3b68261a) and of course the o[fficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.uielement.commandbindings.aspx) d[ocumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx), I trying to use `ApplicationCommands` in my WPF Prism MVVM application.

**My current approach**

After trying different solutions I found out, I ended up with following constellation:

1. I am using the `AttachCommandBindingsBehavior` class mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823872/1865613), which will be used like this in the view:

   ```
   <UserControl>
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <localBehaviors:AttachCommandBindingsBehavior CommandBindings="{Binding CommandBindings}"/>
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   </UserControl>
   ```
2. `MyViewModel` contains a `CommandBindingCollection` property, which will be populated in the constructor:

   ```
   public CommandBindingCollection CommandBindings { get; } = new CommandBindingCollection();

   public MyViewModel()
   {
       this.CommandBindings.AddRange(new[]
       {
           new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Save, this.Save, this.CanSave),
           new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Open, this.Open)
       });
   }
   ```
3. The UserControl `MyView` contains two buttons:

   ```
   <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" Content="Open" />
   <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" Content="Save" />
   ```

*My first question* at this point is: Are the `Executed()` and `CanExecute()` methods already bound to the Command-DependencyProperty of the `Button`? Since it does not work, what did I forgot or made wrong?

*My second question* is: How can I trigger the `CanExecute` of the Command the Button is bound to? The actual use-case: `MyViewModel.CanSave()` returns true, when the user successfully executed the `MyViewModel.Open()` method. Usually, I would call an `DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`, but calling `ApplicationCommands.Save.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` does not execute `MyViewModel.CanSave()`.

Feel free to ask for more information. I will really appreciate your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since it does not work, what did I forgot or made wrong?

The `CommandBindings` property on your behavior is an `ObservableCollection<CommandBinding>`, but you're binding it to a `CommandBindingCollection` in your view model.  Change your view model's property to a `ObservableCollection<CommandBinding>`.

There are also some problems with the `AttachCommandBindingsBehavior` you linked to.  I'm not sure why the answer was accepted, because it's actually quite broken.  The tweaked version below should work, though.

```cs
public class AttachCommandBindingsBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public ObservableCollection<CommandBinding> CommandBindings
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<CommandBinding>)GetValue(CommandBindingsProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandBindingsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandBindingsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CommandBindings",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<CommandBinding>),
            typeof(AttachCommandBindingsBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandBindingsChanged));

    private static void OnCommandBindingsChanged(
        DependencyObject sender,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var b = sender as AttachCommandBindingsBehavior;
        if (b == null)
            return;

        var oldBindings = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<CommandBinding>;
        if (oldBindings != null)
            oldBindings.CollectionChanged -= b.OnCommandBindingsCollectionChanged;

        var newBindings = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<CommandBinding>;
        if (newBindings != null)
            newBindings.CollectionChanged += b.OnCommandBindingsCollectionChanged;

        b.UpdateCommandBindings();
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        UpdateCommandBindings();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.CommandBindings.Clear();
    }

    private void UpdateCommandBindings()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject == null)
            return;

        AssociatedObject.CommandBindings.Clear();

        if (CommandBindings != null)
            AssociatedObject.CommandBindings.AddRange(CommandBindings);

        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    private void OnCommandBindingsCollectionChanged(
        object sender,
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateCommandBindings();
    }
}
```

> How can I trigger the CanExecute of the Command the Button is bound to?

You can *suggest* that WPF's routed command system reevaluate all commands by calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.  The actual reevaluation will occur asynchronously at the `Background` dispatcher priority.  This is the explicit way to do it, but you should know that this already happens *implicitly* upon certain actions, like focus changes and mouse/keyboard button-up events.  The WPF developers tried to make automatic command requerying as seamless as possible, so it "just works" most of the time.

> The actual use-case: `MyViewModel.CanSave()` returns `true` [...]

Just to be clear, as a `CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler`, your `CanSave` method should return `void` and set `CanExecute` to `true` on the event argument.

Comment: Thank you very for your precious advice, sir! I will try this out.